# How to post a form with a <input> with type 'file' and 'multiple' without getting the request black-holed?

Tags: php, cakephp

Good morning everyone.

I have a problem posting a form where I have a : my target is to upload many files with my form, handling the upload in my model, but I can't even get to Model::beforeSave() because my request keeps getting black-holed. Here is the code.

View:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Gallery', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->hidden('id');
echo $this->Form->input('title', array(
    'required'  => true,
    'label'     => false,
    'class'     => 'form-control'
));
echo $this->Form->input('description', array(
    'required'  => true,
    'label'     => false,
    'type'      => 'textarea',
    'class'     => 'ckeditor'
));
echo $this->Form->input('photos.', array(
    'required'  => false,
    'label'     => false,
    'type'      => 'file',
    'class'     => 'form-control',
    'multiple'  => 'multiple'
));
echo $this->Form->end(array(
    'label'     => $button,
    'class'     => 'btn btn-default'
));
```

Controller:

```
public function admin_update($id = null) {
    if ($id != null && !$this->Gallery->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Elemento non valido');
    }
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        if ($this->Gallery->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Galleria salvata', 'default', array(), 'good');
            return $this->redirect(array(
                'admin'     => true,
                'action'    => 'index'
            ));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash('Non sono riuscito a memorizzare la galleria', 'default', array(), 'bad');
    }
    $this->request->data = $this->Gallery->findById($id);
}
```

Model:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('String', 'Utility');
class Gallery extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'gallery';
    public $displayField = 'title';
    public $validate = array(
        'title' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty')
            )
        ),
        'description' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty')
            )
        )
    );

    public function afterSave($created, $options = array()) {
        $dir = new Folder('img/galleries/' . $this->id, true, 0777);

        foreach ($this->data[$this->alias]['photos'] as $Photo) {
            move_uploaded_file($Photo['tmp_name'], 'img/galleries/' . $this->id . '/' . String::uuid()); // I'll add more controls later
        }
    }

    public function beforeDelete($cascade = true) {
        $dir = new Folder('img/galleries/' . $this->id);
        return $dir->delete();
    } 
}
```

So, every time I try to upload my form, my request gets black-holed with this error

```
The request has been black-holed
Error: The requested address '/ciardi/admin/galleries/update' was not found on this server.

Stack Trace
CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/SecurityComponent.php line 239 → SecurityComponent->blackHole(GalleriesController, string)
[internal function] → SecurityComponent->startup(GalleriesController)
CORE/Cake/Utility/ObjectCollection.php line 128 → call_user_func_array(array, array)
[internal function] → ObjectCollection->trigger(CakeEvent)
CORE/Cake/Event/CakeEventManager.php line 242 → call_user_func(array, CakeEvent)
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 675 → CakeEventManager->dispatch(CakeEvent)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 187 → Controller->startupProcess()
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 165 → Dispatcher->_invoke(GalleriesController, CakeRequest)
APP/webroot/index.php line 108 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

The same problem happens even if I try to upload a single image with this same code.
Is there a way to solve my problem without a plugin? Please help me :)

Comment: Is there JS involved? You need to white list the fields or disabled the security component for that action (**NOT** recommended). Also you're not using is_uploaded_file() which should be used to avoid security issues and your implementation has a few more downsides.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't use JS for the upload. I know the code is not perfect and I didn't write it to be secure, but it's still a test on my personal server, just to understand how to make multi-upload work :)
Now I've tried whitelisting with this line of code in my GalleriesController::admin_update() method
    if ($this->Gallery->save($this->request->data, true, array('title', 'description', 'id')))
but still the request gets black-holed. Oh, and I've seen I had a
    die(var_dump($this->request->data));
before calling Model::save(), but the method didn't stop.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem. I simply added a table in my database named 'images' and an Image model. The Gallery::afterSave() method calls Image::save() for each image I'm trying to upload, Image::beforeSave() checks the image with is_uploaded_file() and moves it to the right dir and Image::beforeDelete() helps me keeping the file system clean. That's it.